# Eliminate empty space in the bottom of a element after a CSS TRANSFORM

Tags: css, transform

I have an `iframe` being displayed on my webpage. I want the `iframe` to be responsive on all devices, so i am using CSS transform to fit most of the screen widths. Only problem is when a screen is re-sized and when the CSS transform is being performed, it creates a white space below the `iframe`. Is there any solution to get rid of the white space. Can it be resolved using jquery?

Visit http://vintagebase.com

Below is the example Responsive CSS

```
---#Tablet (Portrait)---

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 959px) {
  body:after {
    content: "768 to 959px";
    background-color: hsla(270,60%,40%,0.7);
  }

  #iframe1{
    width: 125%; 
    -moz-transform:           scale (.8);
    -moz-transform-origin:    0 0;
    -o-transform:             scale(.8);
    -o-transform-origin:      0 0;
    -webkit-transform:        scale(.8);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -ms-transform:            scale(.8);
    -ms-transform-origin:     0 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are setting the iframe height to be something enourmous. don't do that. instead make it 100%.

Comment: ok 100% wont work because <iframe> is in a div which doesnt have any size. try putting iframe out of that div